# deployed a service on k8s but not showing any pods weven when it failed

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I have deployed a k8s service, however its not showing any pods.  This is what I see

`kubectl get deployments`

[image]

It should create on the default namespace

`kubectl get nodes` (this shows me nothing)

[image]

How do I troubleshoot a failed deployment.  The `test-control-plane` is the one deployed by `kind` this is the k8s one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl get nodes`

If above command is not showing anything which mean there is no Nodes in your cluster so where your workload will run ?

You need to have at least one worker node in K8s cluster so deployment can schedule the POD on it and run the application.

You can check worker node using same command

`kubectl get nodes`

You can debug more and check the reason of issue further using

```
kubectl describe deployment <name of your deployment>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out what really went wrong, first follow the steps described in [Harsh Manvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525824/harsh-manvar) in his answer. Perhaps obtaining that information can help you find the problem. If not, [check the logs of your deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-deployments-and-services).  Try to [list your pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources) and see which ones did not boot properly, then [check their logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods).

You can also use the `kubectl describe` on pods to see in more detail what went wrong. Since you are using kind, I include a list of [known errors](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/known-issues/) for you.

You can also see this [visual guide on troubleshooting Kubernetes deployments](https://learnk8s.io/troubleshooting-deployments) and [5 Tips for Troubleshooting Kubernetes Deployments](https://www.copado.com/devops-hub/blog/5-tips-for-troubleshooting-kubernetes-deployments).